# Why can I not enter more than 25 usernames in the jTweetsAnywhere username array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter, twitter-anywhere

This array has two:

```
$('#jTweetsAnywhereSample').jTweetsAnywhere({
    username = ['twitterapi', 'ChromiumDev']
});
```

When the array has more than 25 an "ERROR: Invalid query" message appears.

I don't know if this is related to a Twitter rate limit issue instead of a jTweetsAnywhere issue. I'm using version 1.3.1., and Firefox 17.0.1 and IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went ahead and looked at how it works, I found that Twitter's search API has some limits, including character, and complexity limits, to the query. So by having more than 25 users, it may be passing the 1000 character limit set by twitter. more info here: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search